# Does anyone knows a good menu module?

Tags: 7, routes

I'm looking for a menu module which would show a menu tree like:

```
Menu level 1 (Container)
    |-------Menu level 2
    |-------Menu level 2
    |-------Menu level 2
    |-------Menu level 2
    |-------Menu level 2
Menu level 1 (container)
    |-------Menu level 2
    |-------Menu level 2
Menu level 1
Menu level 1 (container)
    |-------Menu level 2
    |-------Menu level 2
    |-------Menu level 2
Menu level 1
```

It'd be the best if it would be dynamic, but that doesn't really a must.
So anyone knows a Drupal 7 module which is capable of doing this?

Comment: It's not clear to me what the difference between what you ask for and the regular menu system is.

Comment: The regular menu system, does not work dynamically, and you can't make containers with it (only drops down, not a link.)

Comment: So if I interpret you right, the important question is "How can I make 'container' menu items?".

Comment: not just that, it should be dynamic, you should be able to open a submenu without page refresh.

Comment: @Tusk _ I feel you are bit confused of how menus work. Menu's always open up without page refresh as per my knowledge. In Drupal either choose a theme which already supports drop down or else choose modules like Superfish, Megamenu or OM Maximenu etc..

Comment: @Tusk, I think the the question could be reworded significantly.

Comment: @Hacker, "Menu's always open.." and then you list modules. I'm using Zen to create my theme, and the default menu only opens if you click on it, and then it refreshes the page and opens it.

Letharion, people already helped a lot, I don't think my phrasing would be the main problem.

Comment: @Tusk - cool. Good to know that you got the solution

Comment: FYI: I think there's some confusion and this post lacked specificity. I think this person was actually looking for an accordion/tree menu in which these answers would have been appropriate: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2182/is-there-an-accordian-style-menu-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: This answer is no longer valid due to the module not being maintained. Please refer to other menu modules.

[DHTML Menu](http://drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu) may be an solution. It's still in beta for Drupal 7 though.

> DHTML Menu uses Javascript to reduce the number of page loads when using nested menus; this is particularly useful with Drupal's administration system.
>
> Ordinarily in Drupal, in order to see the sub-items in a menu, you need to click the link of this item and wait for a full page load. After enabling DHTML Menu, clicking a menu link once will expand it to reveal its sub-items without reloading the page. A double-click on the item will load the page normally. Additionally, a cookie stores which menus are open and which are closed, so that the state of the menus remain consistent as you navigate around the site.

Comment: DHTML menu has a security vulnerability.

Comment: Not necessarily, the module is just not maintained anymore (and that for more than a year now). Anyway, the answer is more than six years old. ;) But good catch, I wouldn't recommend it anymore.

Comment: Actually it has an explicite security warning and it caused my site to be hacked through javascript. https://www.drupal.org/project/dhtml_menu

Answer (score 4):

[Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) is pretty configurable. You can use classic drop downs or try a mega menu

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Special menu items module](http://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items).  It will let you define a menu item as `<nolink>` so that it can just serve as a parent item.  I have used this on a few projects, and it works mostly well.  Just keep in mind that you will need to do a decent amount of CSS work, though, since many themes/modules assume that menu entries are also links.  Nothing earth shattering though, just a little annoying.

Answer (score 1):

For your situation i would use [superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish).

But to answer your first question (the title of your post):

There's actually a [Drupal.org page](http://drupal.org/node/627128) of contributed menu modules:

> - Jump
> - Superfish
> - Menu block
> - Menu minipanels
> - Nice Menus
> - Nice Primary Menus
> - Site Menu: Site map and sidebar menu
> - Submenu Tree

**Comprehensive Listing on Drupal.org**

Also, if you're hungry for more comprehensive list of contributed menu modules; you're able to search by the category, "menu," in Drupal.org. It provides an [extensive listing](http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_multisitesearch/menu?filters=ss_meta_type%3amodule) of 631 modules though.